# Как объявить сервер Tomcat в Eclipse версии 4.16.0?

Tags: java, сервер, eclipse, tomcat

Пытаюсь объявить сервер в IDE. И если раньше это можно было сделать в разделе меню Window → Preferences и Server → Runtime Environments, то теперь пункт Server оттуда убран (см. изображение). Найти не получилось.

Как объявить сервер в среде разработки Eclipse?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сначала надо создать проект.

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле здесь вот какая штука была. Eclipse есть разных версий, в частности, Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers и Eclipse IDE for Java Developers. Так вот первая версия программы имеет инструменты для web-разработки, а вторая, как понял, нет. По всей видимости, у меня была установлена вторая версия. Но переустанавливать ничего не пришлось. Просто прошел в меню Help -> Eclipse Marketplace, и оттуда скачал пакет инструментов веб-разработки.

После этой процедуры сервер в меню Window -> Preferences стал отображаться.

Затем еще потребовалось установить "JST Server Adapters", чтобы runtime environment Eclipse "увидел" Tomcat. Сделал это через Install New Software в меню Window. Там выбрал сайт Helios - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios (можно и kepler - http://download.ecliplse.org/releases/kepler). В выпавшем списке отметил расширение "Web, XML, and Java EE Development", и в нем уже "чекнул" JST Server Adapters